# How can i get index of the five highest numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

I need a method that returns an array with five positions. The numbers of this arrays mean, in order, the index of the highest number in the array that come in the argument. I have this but i think there´s a better way to do it.

```js
function calculateHighests(array){ // in array[array.lentgth-1] is saved a very low number
  var max1=max2=max3=max4=max5=array.length-1;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i]>array[max5]){
    if(array[i]>array[max4]){
     if(array[i]>array[max3]){
      if(array[i]>array[max2]){
       if(array[i]>array[max1]){
        max1=i;
       } else {
        max2=i;
       }
      } else {
       max3=i;
      }
     } else {
      max4=i;
     }
    } else {
     max5=i;
    }
   }
  }
  res = [max1,max2,max3,max4,max5];
    return res;
 }
 
 var inp = [2, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8, 0];
 
 var out = calculateHighests(inp);
 
 console.log(out);
```

The numbers in the array can be repeated.

Comment: Can number repeat?

Comment: For example if the array is [0,3,7,1,8,3,5,0,2,9], the "res" array should be [9,4,2,6,1]

Comment: Sort the array into a new array, then take the five largest numbers and find their index in the original array

Comment: The `sort`-based answers are great, simple code and clearly understandable.  If you need to do this for very large arrays, you might want to investigate the Max Heap data structure, which would involve much more code, but would be quite a bit faster.  Also, a performant [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) would be a performance improvement, and would presumably be `O(5 * n)`, or `O(k * n)` in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array and then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) get array of indexes

```js
function findMaxPositions(arr,n){
  return arr.slice(0).sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,n).map(x => arr.indexOf(x));
}

console.log(findMaxPositions([0,3,7,1,8,3,5,0,2,9],5));
```

If the numbers can repeat so follow the steps:

- Use `map()` to create array of objects with `index` and `value`
- Then use `sort()` sort the array on the base of value
- Then use `slice()` to get the first `5` elements
- Use `map()` again to convert the array of objects to array of indexes

```js
function findMaxPositions(arr,n){
      return arr.map((val,ind) => ({val,ind})).sort((a,b) => b.val-a.val).slice(0,n).map(x => x.ind);
    }
    
    console.log(findMaxPositions([1,1,1,1,1],5))
```

Comment: @JonasWilms OP didn't specify that numbers could repeat

Comment: @Jonas Wilms You are right I added a version for repeated values

Comment: @JonasWilms What if now i want the index of the five leasts numbers in the array?

Comment: @wasanga7 Just change `b.val-a.val` to `a.val-b.val` This will sort it ascending order

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array and keep the indices:

```
const calculateHighest = arr => arr
  .map((v, i) => ({ v, i }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.v - b.v)
  .slice(0, 5)
  .map(({ i }) => i);
```

Comment: upvote for nice and quick solution. Notice that `sort((a, b) => a.v - b.v)` will sort array in ascending order and will get indexes of least values

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the index-value pair array returned by [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the top 5 indexes

```js
let array = [10, 5, 7, 0, 4, 3, 8]

let output = Object.entries(array)
                    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
                    .slice(0, 5)
                    .map(a => +a[0])
                    
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be to sort the indexes :

```js
var arr = [0,3,7,1,8,3,5,0,2,9];

var result = Object.keys(arr).sort(function(a, b) { return arr[b] - arr[a]; })
                   .slice(0, 5).map(Number);

console.log( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

Comment: What if now i want the index of the five leasts numbers in the array?

Comment: @wasanga7 switch the parameters in the sort function `return arr[a] - arr[b];`

Comment: reverse the comparing method to return arr[a] - arr[b];